# Find the average of an NSMutableArray with valueForKeyPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, average

Currently I'm trying to find a compact way to **average a matrix**. The obvious solution is to sum the matrix, then divide by the number of elements. I have, however, come across a method on the apple developer website that claims this can be done in a simpler way using valueForKeyPath. This is linked here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Here is the example I'm currently working on to try and get it to work:

```
-(void)arrayAverager
{
   NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];
   [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myValue]];
   NSNumber *averageValue = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
   NSLog(@"avg  = %@", averageValue);

}
```

The **problem** is: instead of averaging the array it merely prints out the elements in the array 1 by 1.

UPDATE

```
-(void) pixelAverager

{
    //Put x-coordinate value of all wanted pixels into an array
    NSMutableArray *xCoordinateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];
    [xCoordinateArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:xCoordinate]];
    NSLog(@"avg = %@", [xCoordinateArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.intValue"]);
 }
```

Comment: I can't see where in the link you provided it says to use `@avg.self`. As far as I can tell the correct string is simple `@avg`.

Comment: When I just have @avg it throws the following error:

'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSArrayM 0x6c0c870> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key avg.'

Comment: What do you expect? You create an array with exactly one element! Then the average is the value of that element. - `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"]` works and returns the average value of all elements of that array.

Comment: I thought as xCoordinate was changing it would be added to the mutable array?

Comment: @TonyHematite: But you create a new (empty) `xCoordinateArray` in your method. - How to you call `pixelAverager` and how is your matrix stored?

Comment: I call "pixelAverager" like this :  `[self pixelAverager] `. What I'm essentially doing is trying to get the x coordinates of some pixels into an NSMutableArray.

Like this :  `//Put x-coordinate value of all wanted pixels into an array
    NSMutableArray *xCoordinateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];
    [xCoordinateArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:xCoordinate]];
    for (int v = 0 ; v < [xCoordinateArray count]; v++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"avg = %@", [xCoordinateArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.intValue"]);

            } `

Comment: I am aware I need a count to do so. And it was working before (printing what was in the matrix with the line :  `NSLog(@"x-coordinate here is: %i", [[xCoordinateArray objectAtIndex:v]integerValue]);`

Comment: Your code adds exactly one element to the array! - And by the way, computing the average directly is faster than creating an array, adding all numbers to the array and then using `valueForKeyPath`.

Comment: How would one compute the average directly?

Comment: @TonyHematite: I still don't understand: How are your pixel values stored?

Comment: They're stored in the matrix "xCoordinateArray" and from tests I'm pretty sure they're stored in there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22977/discussion-between-tony-hematite-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `@avg.floatValue` (or `@avg.doubleValue`, or what have you). The `@avg` operator will average the property of the objects in the array specified by the name after the dot. The documentation is confusing on this point, but that is what:

> to get the values specified by the property specified by the key path
>   to the right of the operator

Is saying. Since you have a collection of `NSNumber` objects, you use one of the `*value` accessors, e.g. `floatValue` to get the value of each object. As an example:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void) {
  NSMutableArray *ma = [NSMutableArray array];
  [ma addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
  [ma addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0]];
  [ma addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0]];

  NSLog(@"avg = %@", [ma valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.floatValue"]);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this code returns:

```
$ clang avg.m -framework Foundation -o avg
steve:~/code/tmp
$ ./avg 
2013-01-18 12:33:15.500 avg[32190:707] avg = 2
steve:~/code/tmp
```

The nice thing about this approach is that this work for any collection, homogenous or otherwise, as long as all objects respond to the specified method, `@avg` will work.

**EDIT**

As pointed in the comments, the OP's problem is that he is averaging a collection with one element, and thus it appears to simply print the contents of the collection. For a collection of `NSNumber` objects, `@avg.self` works just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's not currently working for my current code (applied example) so I've put that in the question.

Comment: `valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"` works perfectly to compute the average of an array of numbers.  The OP's problem was that this was applied to arrays of a single element. - Your answer has already been accepted, so maybe you can update it so that future readers are not informed wrongly.

Comment: @MartinR You are correct sir. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MartinR Just as an aside, the `@avg.self` does not work in predicates, but `@avg.floatValue` does, as pointed out in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16359155/644348) - so maybe the `@avg.self` construct is a bit flakey after all. As freespace said, the docs are somewhat unclear.

Comment: @Monolo: I had already seen (and upvoted :-) your question. One difference is that in a predicate, `valueForKeyPath` is sent to each individual element of the array and not to the entire array. - Using `@avg.self` has the advantage that it avoids the conversion to floating point because (contrary to the documentation) the collection operators use decimal numbers internally (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383265/1187415) and is faster (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931719/1187415). - I tried to find a similar solution for your predicate question but failed :-)

Comment: @MartinR Very nice research in that answer, much clearer! I actually filed a bug against the documentation, but I missed the double/NSDecimal part, which seems important.

Comment: Suggestion: Use always the [obj valueForKeyPath:@"avg"] as float. Using [[obj valueForKeyPath:@"avg"] integerValue] gives 0 sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't do like this. The object `Transaction` is a `Modal Class`. This `class` is having three properties, namely

- payee
- amount
- date

Each `row` in this image represents one `Transaction modal object`.

[image]

`transactions` is an `array` which is holding all these rows (`Transaction Modal Objects`).

In these `transactions` array, they are trying to calculate the `Transaction Modal` **amount** field average using the operator `@avg`. So, its like

```
NSNumber *transactionAverage = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.amount"];
```

your array doesn't have the key `self`. So that's the problem

Comment: This is not correct. Each element in the array responds to the selector `self`, and `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"]` works.