# How to add all decimal numbers in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdecimalnumber

I have a `NSMutableArray` which have some `NSDecimalNumber` in it, like `(500,50.80,70,8000)`

Now I want to add all those `decimal numbers` together.

I've tried to use

```
for (NSDecimalNumber *number in self.numbersArray)
{
    NSDecimal *sum += [number decimalValue]
}
```

But failed.

Comment: if your array contains dictionaries then apple provides a single line execution NSNumber *amountSum = [YourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
    NSLog(@"%@",amountSum);

Comment: for more info you can go through this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: @Manohar: You can use KVC also for a plain array: `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByAdding:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber`

Take a look at [NSDecimalNumber Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDecimalNumber *lNumber = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
for (NSDecimalNumber *number in self.numbersArray)
{
    lNumber = [lNumber decimalNumberByAdding:number];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to add all `NSNumber`s in an array is (similar to what @Mahonor said in a comment):

```
NSArray *myArray = ... // array of NSNumber (or NSDecimalNumber) objects
NSNumber *sum = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

---

Contrary to what the [Collection Operators: sum](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178593) states, the numbers in the array are *not* converted to `double`, but to `NSDecimal`. Therefore, ***no precision is lost*** when adding decimal numbers. Even `NSNumber` objects which are not decimal numbers are converted to `NSDecimal` for the addition. The result of the summation is an instance of `NSDecimalValue`.

I verified (or tried to) that in two different ways. First, I ran this code

```
NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.2];
NSNumber *b = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"-5.7"];
NSArray *myArray = @[a, b];
id sum = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

and activated Objective-C message logging by setting the environment variable "NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled=YES". As can be seen in the created "/tmp/msgSends-NNNN" file, `decimalNumber` (and not `doubleValue`) is sent to both number objects.

Second, I created a custom class implementing both `decimalValue` and `doubleValue`, and applied `@sum.self` to an array of objects of the custom class:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) double value;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (NSDecimal)decimalValue
{
    return [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.value] decimalValue];
}

- (double)doubleValue
{
    return self.value;
}

@end

MyClass *a = [MyClass new]; a.value = 1.2;
MyClass *b = [MyClass new]; b.value = -5.7;
NSArray *myArray = @[a, b];
id sum = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

By setting breakpoints in both methods, it is seen that only `decimalValue` is used for the summation (and `valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"` throws an exception if the class does not implement `decimalValue`).

One can also see that `decimalValue` is called from

```
-[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) _sumForKeyPath:]
```

and the assembler code for this method shows that `NSDecimalAdd` is uses to add the numbers.

Comment: Very nice research! Always great to learn something new about the inner workings.

Answer (score 1):

Manohar's suggestion in the comments is not bad. You can indeed use [KVC collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) to make a one-liner out of this: `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.doubleValue"];`, but you potentially lose precision (depending on the numbers you have stored).

You're basically looking for "reduce" functionality; you need to chain calls to `decimalNumberByAdding:` so that each call has the succeeding element of the array as its argument. Doing this on an `NSArray` is easy enough, using `performSelector:withObject:`

```
@implementation NSArray (Reduce)
- (id)reduceUsingSelector: (SEL)sel
{
    id res = [self objectAtIndex:0];
    for( id obj in [self subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){1, [self count]-1}] ){
        res = [res performSelector:sel withObject:obj];
    }

    return res;
}
@end
```

Use this like so: `NSDecimalNumber * sum = [myArray reduceUsingSelector:@selector(decimalNumberByAdding:)];`

The code you have isn't successful because [`NSDecimal`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDecimal) is a struct, not an object; it shouldn't be declared as a pointer, and if it wasn't, you wouldn't be able to add it. That's not the right route to a solution.

Comment: I have fixed the length parameter for the subarray, I hope that is OK.

Comment: Remark: `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"]` works also and returns a NSDecimalNumber object, but I don't know if NSDecimalNumber is used for all intermediate calculations.

Comment: @MartinR: [Collection Operators: sum](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178593) states that each number is transformed to a double. Also it doesnt mentioned NSDecimalNumber, I would assume, that it is done in the same way.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: OK, then using `@sum` *is* prone to precision loss. I just noticed that it always seems to return an instance of NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I have done some testing both with a custom class and with subclassing (using some trickery) NSNumber and NSDecimalNumber. It seems that `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"]` sends `decimalValue:` to each object in the array, contrary to what the documentation says, and uses (as it seems from the assembler code) NSDecimalAdd to add the values.

Comment: @MartinR: that would be great. can you publish your code? I'd like to see it. Also you should post `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"]` as an answer.

Comment: @MartinR: I did some isa swizzeling and came to the same result

Comment: @vikingosegundo: That is exactly what I did (using `object_setClass`)! One can also use "Objective-C message tracing" to verify this, I have written an answer containing this information.