# Using KVC Collection Operators on NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding

I have a method inside a subclass of an NSManagedObject, which returns the total sum of all assets.  Currently it looks like this and works fine

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)totalAssetValue
{
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    for (NSManagedObject *account in [self valueForKey:@"accounts"]) {
        for (NSManagedObject *asset in [account valueForKey:@"assets"]) {
            total = [total decimalNumberByAdding:[asset valueForKey:@"assetAmount"]];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

I would like to use KVC collection operator to eliminate the loops, so I tried this

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)totalAssetValue
}
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"accounts.assets.@sum.assetAmount"];
}
```

However, I receive the following error

> -[__NSSetI decimalValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000000dc70

Do I have the proper syntax to replicate the above loops? or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)totalAssetValue
{
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"accounts.@sum.assets.@sum.assetAmount"];
}
```

Both "accounts" and "assets" are to-many relationships, therefore you need two "@sum"
operators (corresponding to the two nested for-loops in your original code).

Note that it not officially documented (as far as I know) that the Key-Value Coding "@sum"
operator returns an `NSDecimalNumber`, it might be "just" an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thanks and you are correct the documentation states "Each number is converted to a double, the sum of the values is computed, and the total is wrapped as an instance of NSNumber and returned."

Comment: @Cory: Unfortunately, the documentation is not correct, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383265/1187415. It uses `NSDecimal` for the intermediate results, and returns `NSDecimalNumber`. My point was only that we cannot *rely* on that.